# Thymeleaf URL syntax?

Tags: html, css, url, thymeleaf

I'm trying to code a web application.
The problem is that i cant continue working on my project because of a simple misunderstanding of syntax, the line of code:

`<section class="section" th:style="'background-image: url(' + @{/resources/img/---.jpg} + ')'">`

As you can see I am working with thymeleaf and i tried to add a background image to the class of a framework. Didnt know how to edit the URL properly so i found that on the internet. It's working but i wonder why all these extra stuff is added in style. Didnt find anything on the official thymeleaf doc.

Why is there a ' behind the ". And why did i need to add two + ? Is the background image still pairable with other modifiers ? (f.a. no-repeat ?) I tried to add them but i cant just use a comma or a comma with two ' .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highest working principle of Thymeleaf bellow:

```
index.html <--- template
    |
    |
Thymeleaf template engine <--- digests template
    |
    |
HTTP response with HTML content type
```

Thing is that your templates cannot be seen as regular HTML files. They are digested by Thymeleaf template engine. This means that all template parameters are replaced by real values upon digestion.

First, this has been set: `'background-image: url('`. Why so? Because `th:style` is Thymeleaf's tag and Thymeleaf will try to parse all the content assigned to this tag. Text is represented by `''`.

Second, an image from classpath resources is being concatenated to that text via a simple `+` operator. To access and concatenate classpath resource, we use this syntax:

`+ @{/resources/img/---.jpg}`

And finally, we concatenate `)` by using the following syntax: `+ ')'`.

In the end, Thymeleaf will produce something like this:

```
<section class="section" style="background-image: url(/image.jpg)">
```

Comment: Thx for the help, i understand now. But one more question: If i want to add something, lets say background-repeat, do i just separate it with a simple comma ? 

`<body th:style="'background-image: url(' + @{/resources/img/image5test.jpg} + ')' , 'background-repeat: ...'">` 

I feel like it should work but it doesnt.

Comment: Like this basically: `<body th:style="'background-image: url(' + @{/resources/img/image5test.jpg} + ');' + 'background-repeat: ...'">`
Just concatenate more styles and separate them with semicolons.